# How do I configure node_exporter to only display specific metrics from my .prom file?

Tags: linux, bash, prometheus

I am trying to expose metrics with the node_exporter. The metrics are collected with a bash file, that writes them to a .prom file on this path, the default from configuration
`/var/lib/node_exporter`

However, after displaying the collector.systemd stats, the collector only shows the first line/variable from the metrics file

```
# HELP script_runtime Metric read from /var/lib/node_exporter/output.prom
# TYPE script_runtime untyped
script_runtime{application="A",runtime="1685336821"} 1.685336821e+09
```

What should I do?

I tried to point the node_exporter to the .prom file and run it along with systemd collector

Comment: try checking your `.prom` file using [`promtool`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/promtool/). Your file could have some issue, for example with encoding.

Comment: Also, whenever you have such problems, look into logs.